# Frame ticks of a Plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

When I Plot my function (under Plot command) it is seen that all the Frame ticks along Y axis shows the only value -1 but the Graph is okay.I used FrameTicks-> Automatic. However, along X axis it automatically shows the Frame tick in micro meter order.
It may be possible that these type of doubts have already been discussed but I am very sorry to say that I could not find the exact match.
Would you please suggest me what to do or provide me the link, if already exists.

Comment: If the only `y` tick labels are `-1` then the function is essentially constant in the interval and has the value `-1`. Manually, set the `PlotRange` to something like `PlotRange -> {-1.01, -0.99}` and you will probably see a straight line at `-1`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.